# All first array element replaced by last element of second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I am trying to make a list of a pair from one array using another array.

```
function pair(currentPlayer) {
let mainSet = [];
let subSet = [currentPlayer[0], currentPlayer[1], currentPlayer[2]];

for(let i = 0; i < currentPlayer.length - 2; i++) {
    for(let j = 3; j < currentPlayer.length; j++) {
        let set = function() {
            return currentPlayer[j];
        }

        subSet[i] = set();
        mainSet.push(subSet);
    }
}

return mainSet;
}

console.log(pair([0, 2, 5, 7, 8]));
```

I am getting this output

```
[ [ 8, 8, 8 ],[ 8, 8, 8 ],[ 8, 8, 8 ],[ 8, 8, 8 ],[ 8, 8, 8 ],[ 8, 8, 8 ] ]
```

All the array element of sub array is replaced with the last element of the main array. I know the last element of the main set is used for all elements which are to be replaced because of lexical environment structure. I tried different variants of the code like using the third variable declared outside the scope. All tend to give the same output.

Is there something wrong with the structure of this code. Because I am assuming the output of code should be like each element of the subset to be replaced with a 3rd and 4th element respectively and the pair should be pushed to the main set.

Comment: You're not reinitialising `subSet` which means that you're always pushing the same array into `mainSet` and you're always changing the values of `subSet`

Comment: You keep modifying the same array `subSet` and pushing a reference of it to every position in new array

Answer (score 0):

First of all to make it work you can replace your code by this one:

```
function pair(currentPlayer) {
let mainSet = [];
let subSet = [currentPlayer[0], currentPlayer[1], currentPlayer[2]];

for(let i = 0; i < currentPlayer.length - 2; i++) {
    for(let j = 3; j < currentPlayer.length; j++) {
        let set = function() {
            return currentPlayer[j];
        }

        subSet[i] = set();
        mainSet.push(Object.assign([],subSet));
    }
}

return mainSet;
}

console.log(pair([0, 2, 5, 7, 8]));
```

now, some explanation:
As you may noticed, I've changed the push function. 
In your current code, you push always the same array. As in javascript array are pass by reference, if value in array changed your final array will be updated.
You have to break the reference to array (like creating a new array)

If your not famillar with Object.assign you can do the following:

```
for(let i = 0; i < currentPlayer.length - 2; i++) {
    let arr = [];
    for(let j = 3; j < currentPlayer.length; j++) {
        let set = function() {
            return currentPlayer[j];
        }

        arr[i] = set();
        mainSet.push(subSet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```js
var array1 = [0, 2, 5, 7, 8];

// pass a function to map
const map1 = array1.map(function(x, i, arr) {
  return (i>2) ? arr.slice(3) : x;
});

console.log(map1);
// output: Array [0, 2, 5, [7, 8], [7, 8]]
```

Cheers,